# Symfony2 NGINX Unable to create the cache directory

Tags: php, symfony, caching, nginx, centos

I know this may seem as a repeated question but so far I have 4 hours digging around unable to find a straight answer to this. I have setup a brand new CentOS 7 and I installed NGINX (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7) + PHP 5.6 (https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/) and MariaDB.

Following the guides I was able to make the NGINX serve PHP files successfully.

I have a project in Symfony2 which I am trying to get in this server, my problem is when I try to open up http://server/web/app.php. I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (/usr/share/nginx/html/app/cache/prod) ' in ................

I read in the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) that I should work around my permissions so I was able to apply the following:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' |  grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Since I have CentOS 7 from scratch that was the option that I was able to apply. However, I still have the same issue, after this approach these are the other options I've tried:

1. changed the owner for app/cache and app/logs to nginx:nginx
2. changed the permissions to 777 to the above folders
3. verified and re-verified that PHP is running under the nginx user, I had to change this in the www.conf
4. if I do ls -Al it shows that app/cache and app/logs are owned by nginx
5. restarted services after each single change
6. restarted the server completely
7. cleared the cache and performed warmup and still
8. Tried the umask option provided by symfony and still.

So after all these options I still get the same issue, to other people out there with this problem it's simply following the Symfony2 guidelines for applying the ACL and puff, done. But this is not the case.

What am I missing?

Ps: I double checked the permissions of the folder..and I am in the server as root.

**Update 1**

I re-installed CentOS 7 from scratch and followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7 and in combination with Symfony's suggestion for the configuration file and still I get the " Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running into SELinux issues, since CentOS 7 ships with SELinux running by default.

You can test by executing `setenforce 0` to see if that solves the problem.  If that works, you need to configure SELinux to allow the nginx user to write to the cache directory, and then re-enable SELinux.  SELinux does provide some good security, so it would be best to figure out how to configure it properly, as opposed to turning it off completely.

Comment: that did not worked, I am honestly thinking going to CentOS 6.5 to see if it works properly there..

Comment: I doubt that will change anything, to be honest.  You might just try strace'ing the process to see exactly where the error is coming from.  There may be something else less obvious at work here.  Also, trying su'ing to the nginx user and see if you can write into those directories.

Comment: One thing that I was able to have work is the app_dev.php. but it still shows the same error just in symfony2 style, i even chmod 777 the whole project and made the owner nginx

Comment: What happens if you create the `prod` cache directory?

Comment: The folder is created.. When I do the cache:clear it even gets created

Comment: The error above seems to say that it can't create the prod directory.  Is that not the case?  Are you possibly having another problem?  Also, are you running clear:cache as root, and then taking ownership of the directories?

Comment: If the directory does not exists then the error says that it cannot create the prod folder, if I run the clear cache as root the folder gets created and then do chwon to nginx and/or chmod 777 when the folder exists the error then says cannot write to the directory, but when I check the directory it is writeable

Comment: Not sure I have any more ideas without seeing it, try some of the things I mentioned above (su to nginx, strace) and ensure that your application is truly running as nginx (if you're using php-fpm, it might not be).  Good luck.

Comment: FINALLY!, after I reinstalled from scratch I was able to use your setenforce option and it worked!, how can I configure the SELinux to give access to nginx so I can put the setenforce back to 1?

Comment: I wish I could help on that, but I'm not even close to an expert on SELinux, that might be another question for SO.  Glad its getting close at least!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add a local custom rule (policy module), suppose you have your application under the /usr/share/nginx/www directory:

   ```
   semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/usr/share/nginx/www/.+/app/(cache|logs)(/.*)?'
   ```
2. You need to restore the contexts for all the files in that dir:

   ```
   restorecon -Rv /usr/share/nginx/www/your-app-dir
   ```
3. Change the group of the cache and logs directories and add permissions for the group:

   ```
   chgrp -R apache /usr/share/nginx/www/your-app-dir/app/{cache,logs}
   chmod -R 775 /usr/share/nginx/www/your-app-dir/app/{cache,logs}
   ```